I'm curious, when does cloud object storage services increase storage capacity in AZ and regions?
I'm using cloud object storage services such as Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage and Linode. I'm curious, what are the storage capacities of such object storage services per region and AZ (availability zone), and when do they increase the storage capacity in a specific region and AZ? How much usage (in percent) does the storage capacity has to be used for it to be increased by the company who runs it? And also, which operating systems and software do they use internally and do they use the same OS and software in all the AZ in each specific region? Which regions in these cloud storage providers have more storage capacity and usage and which have less? And is this information confidential or is it public?

Based on what I see (and common sense) such information is strictly internal and confidential. Exposing it may give to competitors "some" advantage, used in ads for example. Also this information may give to malicious people additional information for attacks against the infrastructure.
My personal experience show no info about object storage be out of space (based on different regions and AZ).

Azure automatically handles storage scaling for many of its services, regardless of the region. However, there are specifics depending on the type of storage and the service you're using.
For general-purpose v2 storage accounts, Azure automatically scales out to handle increases in storage demand. Each storage account has a limit, but Azure is designed to handle up to that limit automatically.
Blob storage: up to 5 PB in size.
File storage: up to 100 TiB in size.
Other than that, I think you'd need to contact Microsoft to get a bespoke configuration.

By my understanding the OP ask how the things happen on server side, not on client side. How Amazon, Microsoft, Google, etc. handle storage, provided to customer.

I asked about the total capacity in each AZ and region (for all customers) and not about the limits per customer.

They mustn't (shouldn't) offer services when the client and/or the zone/citizenship doesn't allow it (legal, politics, whatever). It isn't my idea, industry regulates that. It can also be [most likely] that it just isn't available in the zone where you're deploying. When that happens to me [and it still it does frequently], I chose another zone at the sacrifice of latency.
